# Make the $ that opens a math environment replace preceding spaces with a single non-breakable?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I find myself spending effort in placing the tilde character before
every inlined math I  type, e.g.,

```
   On 1899, G. Pick proved that 
the area of a simple polygon~$P$ whose vertices are 
located on the integer grid is~$i + b/2 -1$, 
where~$i$ is the number of grid points in the interior of%
~$P$ and~$b$ is the number of grid points on the
the boundary of~$P$.
```

Can anyone think of a way of redefining the opening $ character so 
that it would do that automatically. Many will find this useful, methinks.
Ideally, I would write instead just

```
  On 1899, G. Pick proved that
the area of a simple polygon $P$ whose vertices are 
located on the integer grid is $i + b/2 -1$, 
where $i$ is the number of grid points in the interior of
$P$ and $b$ is the number of grid points on the
the boundary of $P$.
```

I think, but not sure, that this is doable with the following method:

1. Use character other than $ for inline math (or refer internally to `\(` and `\)`)
2. Define $ as an active character which `\unskip`s previous spaces, replacing them with non-breakable space.
3. After un-skipping, let $ redefine itself to do the closing part.
4. The closing $ will invoke `\)` and then will redefine $ as in 2.

An obvious bug of this method would be that displayed math wrapped with $$ would misbehave. I have an unpleasant feeling that there might be more.

Comment: Yes, 2. and then 1. popped into my mind too. One problem with global catcode changes is that they can mess with other packages which authors really didn't thought that `$` would ever by anything then catcode 3. My `tikz-timing` package for example would stop supporting `$` characters in timing strings. You might just do search and replace: `s/ \$/~$/g` instead over your documents.

Comment: The catcode changes will also not work inside macro arguments and environments which collect their body (e.g. `tabularx`, `environ` envionments, ...).

Comment: @Martin — Hmmm, I wonder if `environ` should use `\scantokens` internally to help overcome this problem (doesn't fix it entirely, of course)

Comment: @Martin — but this is only a problem if `$` is not *always* active.

Comment: @Yossi: I'd definitely _not_ put a `~` in front of `$i + b/2 -1$`. So I'd make the question harder and ask for a `~` only in front of `$<single token>$`!

Comment: @Will: The problem is when when the catcode of `$` should be redefined by an active `$`. I was under the impression that is what Yossi means, but know I see that it could be done by active `$`s only. I don't think `environ` should use `\scantokens` by itself. The user could do `\scantokens\expandafter{\BODY}` instead.

Comment: I think I'd go for a new command, `\m` that expanded to `\unskip~\(#1\)` (or whatever the correct syntax is) since, as others have pointed out, you don't actually want to do this all the time.

Comment: @Martin: Well, %s/ \$/~$/g (assuming vi syntax) would indeed carry most of the cases, but not all. You would need to also take care of cases in which the $ is the first character in the line, and of people's habit to indent their lines within environments.

Comment: @Yossi: My point was that this minor things should be better handled with the editor instead of redefining a important character. Could you please mark inline code also in comments with `\``, thanks!

Comment: @Martin: if you are a TeX macros expert, this is indeed a minor question!

Comment: @Yossi: with *minor* I meant that you *simply* have to put a `~` before `$`, which should be done using the editor, not be writing macros for it. Programming it isn't that *minor*.

Comment: Dear @Martin: I guess I was not too clear. What I mean is that sometimes, when our head is all busy with clever macros and smart packages, we forget that there are many novices out there. Getting them to do add the "~" is troublesome. They do not understand why it is necessary and are confused by the semantics. They just want to get the document out quickly and right. So, with the bright work here, we can help these people. I know that people I introduced to LaTeX had lots of problems getting this ~ business.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example using the active characters approach. I'm not against this sort of idea for your own documents, but do note that it's probably not the most robust approach (like Martin comments, this could affect the inner workings of other packages—doing it `\AtBeginDocument` is probably a good idea).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\mathshift=$
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\def$#1${%
  \ifdim\lastskip>\z@ \unskip\textvisiblespace \fi
  \mathshift #1\mathshift
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\({% from fixltx2e
  \ifdim\lastskip>\z@ \unskip\textvisiblespace \fi
  \ifmmode \@badmath \else \mathshift\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction} Hello $a+b$
\section{Not sure $x=y$. $x=z$ though!}
And \( f(x) = x^2 \) too.

We'd better ensure no space gets added if there's nothing before the maths:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$a$ & $b$ \\
$c$ & $d$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In order to make the example actually *show* the idea, I've used a visible space instead of a hard space. Remove `\textvisiblespace` above with `~` for your actual work `:)`

Also, I've assumed above that you're not using `$$...$$` for display math, as strictly speaking it's not valid LaTeX syntax.

Answer (score 2):

One way for not breaking other people's packages is to rely on the fact that package writers tend to be conservative, and adhere to ASCII. So, I would redefine the same set of macros that Will did, but have these parameterized by the math character, which can default, or not default, to `$`.

I am clueless as to how one can do this, but just imagine you could write

```
\usepackage[begin=〈, end=〉]{nbsm}
```

and then proceed, wrapping your inlined math with `〈` and `〉`. Or if you are the daring type,

```
\usepackage[begin=$, end=$]{nbsm}
```

Comment: Puh, I'm not sure, but is this really an _answer_?

Comment: @Hendrik, call it a partial answer if you like. Or, think of it as a full answer (rewrite Will's code with 〈 and 〉), which raises, on its way, another small question.