# Automatic non-breakable spaces?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

Very often I have to manually add non-breakable spaces to make things look better. For instance:

- see~\cite{Bla98}
- for all~$x$
- see Section~\ref{sect:bla}

It looks specific enough so that it could be automated: avoid line breaking before a citation/ref/small-math-thingy.

Is there any package doing this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`cleveref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref). It covers at least your third bullet point. For the first two, I don't know of a general solution for these. Consider that the usage may be context-specific; for example, the non-breaking space may be desired for bracketed/numerical citations, but might not be required for author-year type citations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's possible for commands like `\cite` or `\ref` and difficult for `$`. Example for  `\ref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=5.5cm \parindent=0pt %%%% only for demo
\let\myRef\ref
\renewcommand\ref{\unskip~\myRef}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}\label{sect:bla}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

xxxxx xxx xxx xxx  xxxx    see Section \myRef{sect:bla}  %%% the original ref

xxxxx xxx xxx xxx  xxxx    see Section \ref{sect:bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like that, thanks! As for $, some people are discussing it here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11616/make-the-that-opens-a-math-environment-replace-preceding-spaces-with-a-single

Comment: it doesn't make sense for `$` in _all_ cases. You could refedeine `\(...\)` instead

Comment: @Herbert -- yes, one *could* redefine `\{...\}`, but that's adding two keystrokes as well as resetting one's thinking.  it would be more efficient to reset one's thinking to initially always enter `xxx~$...$`, which is a net change of 0 keystrokes.